# Could Youtubers use the default legal system against people who unfairly use their content?

Tags: copyright, youtube

If there is a youtuber who does XYZ and another youtuber does a reaction video on that content, are they allowed to use the legal default such as a cease and desist or a DMCA (or some other form of copyright claim) if they feel that YouTube's system is neither compensatory enough nor punishing enough? If it is possible, is it worth it (especially considering how reaction-channels are now including people who effectively narrate (possible criticism and review) over someone else's channel (e.g narrating what a parkour artist is doing))?

Furthermore, is this isolated to just YouTube?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube does not purport to take works that have been uploaded to YouTube outside of generally applicable copyright law or the DMCA notice and takedown system.

See https://www.youtube.com/intl/en_us/howyoutubeworks/policies/copyright/#making-claims

While YouTube may provide *additional* tools (content matching, etc.), it notes that DMCA notification is available to anyone.